# Adaptive Battery or Sleeping Apps - Samsung devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I access Adaptive Battery or Sleeping Apps within Samsung devices?

I can't find any public library/api for this. I need to have this information within the code. I'm using kotlin for my app.